# axis ticklabel does not load properly in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I have two data series (actual data and a forecast) connecting in one point. Yet, the labels only load for the first series. I need to show all dates. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Data1.csv}
Period,spot,forecast

jun 15,1.93,
jul 15,2.12,
ago 15,2.23,
sep 15,1.81,
oct 15,1.76,
nov 15,1.18,
dic 15,1.12,1.12
ene 16,,0.80
feb 16,,0.88
mar 16,,0.84
abr 16,,0.93
may 16,,1.03
jun 16,,1.55

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{table/col sep = comma}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xticklabels from table={Data1.csv}{Period},
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style={rotate=45},           
            ]
            \addplot[smooth] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=spot, col sep = comma] {Data1.csv};
            \addplot[dashed,red] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=forecast, col sep = comma] {Data1.csv};           
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result is this:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xtick=data` only uses the data from the first `\addplot` command. In your case, you can use `xtick={0,...,100}` (or some other large upper value):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Data1.csv}
Period,spot,forecast
jun 15,1.93,
jul 15,2.12,
ago 15,2.23,
sep 15,1.81,
oct 15,1.76,
nov 15,1.18,
dic 15,1.12,1.12
ene 16,,0.80
feb 16,,0.88
mar 16,,0.84
abr 16,,0.93
may 16,,1.03
jun 16,,1.55

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{table/col sep = comma}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xticklabels from table={Data1.csv}{Period},
            xtick={0,...,100},
            xticklabel style={rotate=45, anchor=north east, yshift=0.5ex},       
            enlarge x limits={abs=0.5}
            ]
            \addplot[smooth] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=spot, col sep = comma] {Data1.csv};
            \addplot[dashed,red] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=forecast, col sep = comma] {Data1.csv};           
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I see that this is mentioned in just a line in section 4.15.1. Still, I fail to see why using {0,..,100} works.